# screen inside the conda environment doesnt work

Tags: anaconda, conda, gnu-screen

If I am inside a conda environment which has lets say tensorflow installed and if I go to screen and then `python -c "import tensorflow";`, it says module not found. However it works well without screen.

Comment: What is the output of `which python` in both cases? How are you ensuring that conda can be used? Editing .bash_profile?

Comment: @rgaut Once you enter the screen. Deactivate and activate the environment again. This is a dumb way to overcome the bug. But works.

Answer (score 37):

I have the same problem: I activated one of my conda environments, let's say *my_env*, and I can use tensorflow in *my_env*. Then, I go to screen. Here, I can no longer import tensorflow. This is weird because within the screen, I still see *my_env* activated in "conda env list" or tensorflow listed in "conda list".

One workaround for me was to deactivate that environment before going into screen. After going into screen I activate *my_env*. Then, I was able to use tensorflow included in that *my_env*.

Comment: Thanks! Turning off env before entering screen worked!

Comment: Your workaround worked for me as well. It is weird though and this bug should definitely be reported and fixed.

Comment: In my case I also needed to create a new screen after deactivating. Detaching, deactivating env and re-attaching didn't work.

Answer (score 20):

All you need to do is to deactivate the environment before entering screen

```
source deactivate
```

Then enter the screen

```
screen -R my_screen
```

Then activate the environment

```
source activate myenv
```

This is a bug in screen. It will show the environment `myenv` but it is actually not activated. But the screen variable says it is already activated. Hence, you cannot activate it again in screen.

The solution is to deactivate outside the screen. Then get into the screen. And activate the environment again.

Answer (score 3):

This issues is created by having a line like to following in your $HOME/.bashrc file:

```
export PATH=$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

When screen starts it will run your .bashrc script again and cause the path to be prepended with another version of $HOME/anaconda3/bin. Even if you activate your virtual environment again in the screen session the shell will end up using the wrong copy of python.

The recommended way to fix this with Anaconda > 4.4 is to remove the line that sets the path and add the following to your .bashrc file

```
. $HOME/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

This has the additional advantage that you can now activate and deactivate anaconda environments using the conda command. e.g.

```
conda activate myenv
```

For further information check out https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#440-2017-12-20

Comment: Upvoted, but I need to verify that this indeed is the cause of the problem :)

Comment: Using `conda activate myenv` is a bad idea. It is always better to use `source activate myenv`

Comment: is there a way to start screen and automatically put it in the save conda env as in the parent terminal.? I tried editing .screenrc but that failed (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57705407/keep-the-same-conda-env-after-entering-screen)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is sart `screen` first, and then activate the conda environment `conda activate my_env`